# Change highlighted file colors

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Here, `index.ts` is selected, but the explorer doesn't have focus, and the color associated with this is barely discernible from the background (fwiw I'm using VSCode Dark+ theme).

Where in the settings can I change this color? Again, it's the highlight color for a file in the explorer when the file is selected but the explorer doesn't have focus. I see the same color whether it's the main file/project explorer, or the file list in a list of diffs, and surely other places. I imagine it's the same setting, but I can't find it anywhere.

[image]

Comment: So you want to change the background color behind the selected file name? If so -- AFAIK it should be part of the theme itself (which is not configurable from the GUI settings). Try contacting the theme author about it.

Comment: That just seems surprising since you can change practically every other color in the UI

Comment: Yes, you can change editor area colors (syntax highlighting etc), Terminal, Debugger, VCS status (file name colors), Diff& Merge, some other bits. But things like GUI colors are configured via Themes and normally themes do not have any configuration options in the UI (since mostly they are just XML files). Material UI Theme plugin offers customization via UI for their themes (at very least certain elements)